# Передача ответа команды ls в массив

Tags: bash

Скрипт должен заполнить массив list именами файлов текущего каталога, чтобы в дальнейшем можно было по очереди эти файлы обрабатывать самыми разными способами в зависимости от имени.

Выдает ошибку

> строка 2: $list: неоднозначное перенаправление

Плохо знаю синтаксис языка, чтобы написать самому правильно. Прошу подсказки

```
#!/bin/bash
ls -1 > $list
echo ${list[2]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

получить результат выполнения команды: `$(команда)`.

поместить строки в массив: `m=('строка1' 'строка2')`

получить первый элемент массива: `echo ${m[0]}`

всё вместе:

```
$ cd /
$ list=($(ls))
$ echo ${list[0]}
bin
```

---

**предупреждение**: строки в данном случае отделяются пробелами, поэтому если в именах файлов/каталогов есть пробелы, элементов массива будет больше, чем файлов/каталогов.

чтобы этого избежать, лучше не «парсить» вывод программы `ls`, а [получить список файлов/каталогов «нативными» средствами](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/17005/110559):

```
$ list=(*)
```